# React Google maps - Map jumps when clicking on a marker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-maps

Im helping a client with a project (which i did not code). They are using the [@react-google-maps/api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api) to display a map with markers, and when you click a marker you will get a small info box displaying some information.

The problem is, when you click one of these markers... the map sort of "jumps", and not in a smooth way and they asked me to try get rid of it. But i really cant figure out by the code what is causing this.

Look at the behavior in this .GIF
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3z9x.gif)

I will provide the code for both the map component itself and the marker component.

Google maps file

```
import { Order, Tour } from '@api/preplans'
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'
import { DirectionsRenderer, GoogleMap, MarkerF } from '@react-google-maps/api'
import { useMarkerColors } from 'hooks/useMarkerColors'
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import { useGoogleMaps } from '../../../contexts/GoogleMaps'
import DirectionsResponse from './DirectionsResponse'
import SelectedTourMarker from './SelectedTourMarker'
import ToursList from './ToursList'
import UnplannedInfo from './UnplannedInfo'

type Props = {
  tours: Tour[] | undefined
  unplannedOrders: Order[] | undefined
}

const Map = ({ tours, unplannedOrders }: Props) => {
  const [tourIndex, setTourIndex] = useState(0)
  const [allTours, setAllTours] = useState(false)
  const [allChecked, setAllChecked] = useState(false)
  const [_map, setMap] = useState<google.maps.Map | null>(null)
  const colors = useMarkerColors(tours?.length || 0)
  const [showInfoWindow, setShowInfoWindow] = useState<string>('')
  const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState({
    lat: tours?.[tourIndex].orders[0].y || 0,
    lng: tours?.[tourIndex].orders[0].x || 0
  })
  const [selectedTours, setSelectedTours] = useState([0])
  const [showUnplOrders, setShowUnplOrders] = useState(false)
  const { isLoaded, loadError } = useGoogleMaps()

  const directionsResponse = null
  const distance = ''
  const duration = ''

  const mapOptions: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    styles: [{}],
    zoomControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
    fullscreenControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scrollwheel: true,
    draggable: true
  }

  const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback() {
    setMap(null)
  }, [])

  const items =
    colors.length > 0 && tours
      ? tours
          .map((t, i) => ({ ...t, markerColor: colors[i] }))
          .filter((_el, ind) => selectedTours.includes(ind))
      : []

  const handleAllChecked = (checked: boolean) => {
    setAllChecked(checked)
    setShowUnplOrders(checked)
    setSelectedTours(checked ? tours?.map((_, i) => i) || [] : [])
    setAllTours(!allTours)
  }

  const unplannedChange = (
    _e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    checked: boolean
  ) => {
    if (checked) setShowUnplOrders(true)
    else setShowUnplOrders(false)
  }

  const addMarkers = (checked: boolean, ind: number) => {
    setTourIndex(ind)
    setAllTours(false)
    setAllChecked(false)

    if (checked) {
      const newItems = [...selectedTours, ind]
      if (newItems.length === tours?.length) {
        setAllChecked(true)
      }
      setSelectedTours(newItems)
    } else {
      if (allChecked) {
        setAllChecked(false)
      }
      setSelectedTours(selectedTours => selectedTours.filter(t => t !== ind))
    }
  }

  return (
    <Grid item md={9} xs={12}>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={9}>
          <div>
            {loadError && (
              <Typography variant="subtitle2">
                Map cannot be loaded right now, sorry.
              </Typography>
            )}

            {isLoaded && (
              <GoogleMap
                zoom={8}
                center={mapCenter}
                options={mapOptions}
                mapContainerStyle={{
                  width: '100%',
                  height: '540px'
                }}
                onLoad={map => setMap(map)}
                onUnmount={onUnmount}
              >
                {items.map(item =>
                  item.orders?.map((order, ind) => (
                    <SelectedTourMarker
                      key={ind}
                      order={order}
                      ind={ind}
                      tourIndex={tourIndex}
                      markerColor={item.markerColor}
                      tours={tours}
                      showInfoWindow={showInfoWindow}
                      setShowInfoWindow={setShowInfoWindow}
                      setMapCenter={setMapCenter}
                      routeNumber={item.vehicle?.vehicleId || ''}
                    />
                  ))
                )}
                {directionsResponse && (
                  <DirectionsResponse
                    tours={tours}
                    tourIndex={tourIndex}
                    distance={distance}
                    duration={duration}
                  />
                )}
                {directionsResponse && (
                  <DirectionsRenderer directions={directionsResponse} />
                )}
                {showUnplOrders && (
                  <>
                    {unplannedOrders?.map((order, ind) => (
                      <MarkerF
                        onClick={() => setShowInfoWindow(order.id)}
                        key={ind}
                        position={{
                          lat: order.y,
                          lng: order.x
                        }}
                      >
                        {showInfoWindow === order.id && (
                          <UnplannedInfo order={order} />
                        )}
                      </MarkerF>
                    ))}
                  </>
                )}
              </GoogleMap>
            )}
          </div>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={8} md={3}>
          <ToursList
            allChecked={allChecked}
            handleAllChecked={handleAllChecked}
            tours={tours}
            unplannedOrders={unplannedOrders}
            unplannedChange={unplannedChange}
            selectedTours={selectedTours}
            addMarkers={addMarkers}
            colors={colors.map(c => c.fill)}
            showUnplOrders={showUnplOrders}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )
}

export default Map
```

SelectedTourMarker file

```
import { Order, Tour } from '@api/preplans'
import Check from '@mui/icons-material/Check'
import Close from '@mui/icons-material/Close'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog'
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions'
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle'
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl'
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel'
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem'
import OutlinedInput from '@mui/material/OutlinedInput'
import Select from '@mui/material/Select'
import useTheme from '@mui/material/styles/useTheme'
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip'
import { InfoWindowF, MarkerF } from '@react-google-maps/api'
import { useQueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query'
import { usePreplanMutations } from 'hooks/mutations/preplan'
import { useGetPreplan } from 'hooks/queries/preplans'
import { MarkerColor } from 'hooks/useMarkerColors'
import moment from 'moment'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { makeStyles } from 'tss-react/mui'

import { MoveOrderArgs } from '../Tabs'

type Props = {
  order: Order
  showInfoWindow: string
  setShowInfoWindow: (id: string) => void
  ind: number
  tourIndex: number
  tours: Tour[] | undefined
  markerColor: MarkerColor
  routeNumber: string
  setMapCenter: (center: { lat: number; lng: number }) => void
}

const SelectedTourMarker = ({
  order,
  setShowInfoWindow,
  showInfoWindow,
  ind,
  tourIndex,
  tours,
  markerColor,
  setMapCenter,
  routeNumber
}: Props) => {
  const { classes } = useStyles()
  const theme = useTheme()
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  const params = useParams()
  const { data: currentPlan } = useGetPreplan(params.id)
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()
  const { replanRoute, recalculateRoute } = usePreplanMutations()

  const [selectedRoute, setSelectedRoute] = useState('')
  const [showDialogEta, setShowDialogEta] = useState(false)
  const [sourceTripId, setSourceTripId] = useState('')
  const [routes, setRoutes] = useState<Tour[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentPlan) {
      setRoutes(currentPlan.tours)
    }
  }, [currentPlan])

  const sortFn = (a: Order, b: Order) => a.stopIndex || 0 - (b.stopIndex || 0)

  const handleSelectMove = (etaOutsideTimeWindow: boolean, stopId: string) => {
    moveOrdersToRoute({
      sourceRouteId: sourceTripId,
      targetRouteId: selectedRoute,
      orderIds: [stopId],
      recalculateTarget: etaOutsideTimeWindow
    })
  }

  const moveOrdersToRoute = ({
    sourceRouteId,
    targetRouteId,
    orderIds,
    recalculateTarget
  }: MoveOrderArgs) => {
    const sourceRoute = routes.find(r => r.tripId === sourceRouteId)
    const newSourceOrders = (
      sourceRoute?.orders.filter(order => !orderIds.includes(order.id)) || []
    ).sort(sortFn)

    const movedOrders = (sourceRoute?.orders || [])
      .filter(o => orderIds.includes(o.id))
      .map((order, i) => ({ ...order, stopId: 9999 + i }))

    const targetRoute = routes.find(r => r.tripId === targetRouteId)
    const newTargetOrders = [
      ...(targetRoute?.orders || []),
      ...movedOrders
    ].sort(sortFn)

    const updatedRoutes = routes.map(route => {
      if (route.tripId === sourceRouteId) {
        return { ...route, orders: newSourceOrders }
      }
      if (route.tripId === targetRouteId) {
        return { ...route, orders: newTargetOrders }
      }
      return route
    })

    replanRoute(
      {
        planId: currentPlan?.id || '',
        vehicleId: sourceRoute?.vehicle?.vehicleId || '',
        orderIds: newSourceOrders.map(o => o.id)
      },
      {
        onSuccess: () => {
          if (recalculateTarget) {
            recalculateRoute(
              {
                planId: currentPlan?.id || '',
                vehicleId: targetRoute?.vehicle?.vehicleId || '',
                orderIds: newTargetOrders.map(o => o.id)
              },
              {
                onSuccess: (_, { planId }) => {
                  setRoutes(updatedRoutes)
                  queryClient.invalidateQueries(['preplan', planId])
                }
              }
            )
          } else {
            replanRoute(
              {
                planId: currentPlan?.id || '',
                vehicleId: targetRoute?.vehicle?.vehicleId || '',
                orderIds: newTargetOrders.map(o => o.id)
              },
              {
                onSuccess: (_, { planId }) => {
                  setRoutes(updatedRoutes)
                  queryClient.invalidateQueries(['preplan', planId])
                }
              }
            )
          }
        }
      }
    )
  }

  return (
    <MarkerF
      label={{
        text: `${ind + 1}`,
        color: theme.palette.secondary.contrastText,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(12),
        className: classes.markerLabel
      }}
      onClick={() => (
        setShowInfoWindow(order.id),
        setMapCenter({ lat: order.y, lng: order.x })
      )}
      position={{
        lat: order.y,
        lng: order.x
      }}
      key={`${order.id}-${ind}`}
      icon={{
        path:
          'M12 2C8.13 2 5 5.13 5 9c0 5.25 7 13 7 13s7-7.75 7-13c0-3.87-3.13-7-7-7Z',
        fillColor: markerColor.fill,
        strokeColor: markerColor.stroke,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 1.5,
        rotation: 0,
        scale: 2,
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 30),
        labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(12, 10)
      }}
    >
      {showInfoWindow === order.id && (
        <InfoWindowF
          position={{
            lat: order.y,
            lng: order.x
          }}
          onCloseClick={() => setShowInfoWindow('')}
          options={{
            minWidth: 175,
            disableAutoPan: false
          }}
        >
          <div>
            <p>
              <strong>{order.recipientName}</strong>
            </p>
            <p>{order.address.split(',')[0]}</p>
            <p>Order: {order.orderReference}</p>
            <p>
              Tid:
              {moment(order.timeWindowStart).format('HH:mm')} -
              {moment(order.timeWindowEnd).format('HH:mm')}
            </p>
            <p>
              Stop: {ind + 1} of {tours?.[tourIndex].orders.length}
            </p>
            <p>Ruttnr: {routeNumber}</p>
            <hr
              style={{
                color: markerColor.fill
              }}
            />
            <FormControl
              variant="outlined"
              sx={{
                width: '100%',
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                marginTop: '0.2rem'
              }}
              size="small"
            >
              <InputLabel shrink id="move-stop">
                {t('PlanningDetailView.text_move')}
              </InputLabel>
              <Select
                labelId="move-stop"
                id="demo-select-small"
                input={
                  <OutlinedInput
                    sx={{ fontSize: '0.8rem' }}
                    size="small"
                    notched
                    label={t('PlanningDetailView.text_move')}
                  />
                }
                displayEmpty
                value={selectedRoute}
                onChange={e => {
                  setSelectedRoute(e.target.value)
                  setSourceTripId(tours?.[tourIndex].tripId || '')
                  setShowDialogEta(true)
                }}
              >
                <MenuItem value="">
                  <em>None</em>
                </MenuItem>
                {tours?.map(tour => (
                  <MenuItem value={tour.tripId} key={tour.tripId}>
                    {tour?.vehicle?.vehicleId}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
          </div>
        </InfoWindowF>
      )}
      <Dialog
        open={showDialogEta}
        onClose={() => setShowDialogEta(false)}
        aria-labelledby="eta-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="eta-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="eta-dialog-title">
          {t('PlanningDetailView.text_eta_dialog')}
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogActions>
          <Tooltip
            title={t('PlanningDetailView.text_eta_dialog-tooltip')}
            disableFocusListener
          >
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="secondary"
              onClick={() => {
                setShowDialogEta(false)
                handleSelectMove(false, order.id)
              }}
              autoFocus
            >
              <Check />
              {t('PlanningDetailView.text_optimize_route')}
            </Button>
          </Tooltip>

          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => {
              setShowDialogEta(false)
              handleSelectMove(true, order.id)
            }}
          >
            <Close />
            {t('PlanningDetailView.text_dont_optimize_route')}
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </MarkerF>
  )
}
const useStyles = makeStyles()(() => ({
  markerLabel: {
    textShadow: '0px 0px 3px #000'
  }
}))

export default SelectedTourMarker
```

I have tried to invoke using the panTo function, (which according to some googling would make this smoother?) but without any success. or see if theres any prop that possible could affect that the onClick center the map slightly below the pin, and then scrolls the map a bit.

Comment: Maybe some help: https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/issues/134

Comment: One note: "Moment.js is a legacy project, now in maintenance mode. In most cases, you should choose a different library." [Here are some alternatives.](https://www.skypack.dev/blog/2021/02/the-best-javascript-date-libraries/)

Comment: Im aware that moment is a legacy project, it will be replaced in the future